# MRU Recent Document History for WPF RibbonApplicationMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, mru

How to add a "**Recent Document**" history to WPF `RibbonApplicationMenu`, and what is the best way to do so?

I have looked into [RecentFileList](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/RecentFileList.aspx) which is the closest thing I found on Google and SO, but it only applies to `MenuItem`. It is not flexible enough to add the MRU to different controls. What is the best approach to do this? Write to and read from the registry? Or save the filaPath to a hidden text file somewhere and read off it (easier, perhaps) ?

Comment: I would recommend a SQLite database per user for data like MRU list

Comment: SQLite database for a mere MRU would be an overkill. You could use application settings to store MRU; myabe in a StringCollection type setting.